# If the system has infinitely many solutions, then any row echelon form [ A | ⃗ b ] must contain a row of zeros?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, education

I am stuck on a math question for my linear algebra midterm regarding REF.

The problem says: Consider a system of linear equations with augmented matrix $[ A \ \ |\ \   \vec b ]$. If the system has infinitely many solutions, then any row echelon form $[ A \ \ |\ \   \vec b ]$ must contain a row of zeros. True or False?

I said true since 0x = 0 would have infinite amount of solutions. However, according to the solution sheet, it says it's false.

The solution: "This statement if FALSE. The system with augmented matrix

```
1, 0, 2  | 1
0, 1, −3 | −1
```

is in REF and is consistent with infinitely many solutions (the third variable is free) but has no row of zeros."

I don't get how this has infinite amount of solutions. My understanding was that something like 0x=0 would have infinite amount of solutions since any value of x would make the the equation equal to 0.

Can someone explain? How does the free variable play into this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a pivot in every column? If not, there will be free variable(s).

Comment: For the example given in The solution, any tuple in the form $(-2z+1, 3z-1, z)$ is a solution.